# KafkaProducer Transaction in psringboot application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to execute some code after sending all messages on kafka topic successfully. I have read a lot of artical. got to know we can send messages using transaction.

```
kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(operations -> {
            for (String s : request) {
                kafkaTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,key,s));
            }
            return null;
        });
```

i tried this short of code but not sure how to excecute some code after this transaction executed successfully. I tried kafkaProducer also by starting the transation but that also not working for my case.It would be helpful if there is any idea.

Comment: What did you try, and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: i mean, i tried to produce one more msg such as 'x' on kafka after above transaction completed. but in my case before completing transaction 'X' is consumed by consumer. and for x msg i am using same kafka topic. so i need to know how can i restrict that X msg should not be consumed before transaction complete.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consumers must have `isolation.level=read_committed` to not see records until they are committed.
2. There is no way to prevent a consumer from seeing a record that was sent outside of a transaction.